# Gradle subprojects and allprojects repeats for each project?

Tags: maven, gradle

So it seems that if I:

1. Create a "profile" (similar to maven) script and put nothing in the profile but a println.
2. Then call it and specify that profile.

The output is printed once for each sub-project or once for each project depending on whether or not the code for loading that profile is located in `allprojects {}` or `subprojects{}`.  This is terrible. How can I have it run once and only once but scoped to all projects? Please say I'm not stuck with this.  We have a really large build. Right now it is SLOWER than maven. Speed was the reason for this conversion so naturally I'm looking for optimizations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to collaborate more on your problem. What kind of profiles are you using? Gradle doesn't really have those, you just conditionally apply logic, base on used properties. If you just want to run some code only once for build, you can still do it easily in the main section outside of `allprojects` or `subprojects`

I.e:

```java
//file: $root/build.gradle
if (project.hasProperty('profile1')) {
  apply from: file("$rootDir/profile1.gradle")
}
```

..

```java
//file: $root/settings.gradle
rootProject.name = 'test'

include ':first'
include ':second'
```

..

```java
//file: $root/profile1.gradle
allprojects {
  println 'allprojects: ' + project.name
}

subprojects {
  println 'subprojects: ' + project.name
}

println 'once: ' + project.name
```

..

```java
//$root/first/build.gradle
//empty
```

..

```java
//$root/second/build.gradle
//empty
```

Than run

```java
gradle build -Pprofile1
```

You will get the following:

```java
allprojects: test
allprojects: first
allprojects: second
subprojects: first
subprojects: second
once: test
```

Just as you would expect...

Comment: This was the answer. Sorry but I'm coming from Java and I've still got the "You can't color outside the lines" mindset. In other words it never occurred to me to put the block of code that loads the profiles outside the braces, which would be no-mans-land in Java. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly then, something along the lines of the following show help you:

```
// in root build.gradle
ext.taskRan = false

subprojects {
  build.doFirst{
    if (! rootProject.ext.taskRan ) {
       rootProject.ext.taskRan = true
       println "do task"
    }
}
```

If you create an ext property in the root build.gradle then all subprojects will have access to it. This can enable you to do all sorts of tricks. Mostly I use it to set project wide variable like where it should place library files after a build task is ran.